# He didn't so much as thank me OR to thank me?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

I have heard both ways 'He didn't so much as thank me' and 'He didn't so much as to thank me'. Which is correct and is the other wrong or can it be used colloquially? 
Thank you.

Comment: [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=much+as+thank+me%2Cmuch+as+to+thank+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmuch%20as%20thank%20me%3B%2Cc0) can't find _much as to thank me_.

Comment: You don't say **He didn't to thank me* so you don't say **He didn't so much as to thank me.*

Comment: I wonder where you've heard “He didn't so much as to thank me”—I have my doubts that it was from native English speakers.

Comment: I've heard similar phrasing from many native people @JanusBahsJacquet.  It's a peculiarity to add "to" in a phrase such as *"have him to reboot his computer"*.  I've only heard this used by African-Americans and in many cases, by very well educated people.  I believe it must be a colloquialism.

Answer (score 1):

Of the two versions you offer, the normal idiomatic wording in English is "X didn't so much as thank me." You might be able to work "so much as to" into a sentence with "thank you" in an idiomatically normal way, but only by drastically revising the sentence so that it it no longer means "X didn't even thank me." For example, you might say something like this:

> X didn't interrupt our conversation to talk about getting the new job so much as to thank me.

There is nothing outlandish about a sentence structured in this way, but here the "so much as to" functions as part of a comparison between A and B framed as "not to do A so much as to do B"—a situation very different from the original one. Still, someone not fluent in English idioms might mistakenly suppose that this structure justifies building a sentence with the structure "X didn't so much as to thank me"—or might get the two structures tangled up.

As earlier commenters have pointed out, however, an expression of the form "X didn't so much as to thank me" is not normal in idiomatic English.